# How should I approach my store manager about a colleague's lie?

Tags: unprofessional-behavior

The fairly new manager of our retail store relies heavily on the office manager, who knows the ins & outs of the store more fully.  I recently found out that the office manager told the manager that myself and another employee wanted a different employee fired.  This was completely fabricated.  Many other things have come to light which reveal this person is a manipulator and has done similar things to others.

The employees involved have decided that it won't do any good to tell the manager because he needs the office manager too much to run the business.  I am having a very difficult time not addressing this serious issue and having to work with this lying person.  I'm considering speaking to the store manager in strictest confidence so at least it will be out in the open between him & myself.

How can I address this issue with the manager effectively?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Is this wise when you know out-and-out fabrication is occurring? I understand the desire to keep one's head down until necessary, but in a situation like this, isn't it possible that it may well be too late to do anything by the time that happens?

Comment: Too late for what?

Comment: What if  the office manager don't really knows the ins & outs and he just faking it? What if one of you is better for his role and will make store run better (because floor experience)?

Comment: What "other things have come to light"? It'd be useful to get a broader view of the office manager's behavior. It makes a difference if this gossipy stunt is the worst of it vs. the tip of the iceberg.

Answer (score 9):

Your OP reads a lot like a very strict, very false, very extreme dichotomy.  It sounds like the dichotomy is between you doing absolutely nothing, and you attempting to get the office manager fired ("The employees involved have decided that it won't do any good to tell the manager because he needs the office manager too much to run the business").

There is a midway point: You should tell the store manager that you (and whatever other employees are implicated in the office manager's tall tale) did not do or say anything of the kind that he was told by the office manager.  Do not imply that the office manager is a consistent liar or trying to undermine someone or something or whatever.  Just stick to the facts: The store manager was told something that wasn't true, and that's where your conversation should begin and end.  After that, leave it to the store manager to decide what he wants to do about it, if anything.

Comment: Wow, a lot of varied feedback here. I'm not trying to get the office manager fired. What concerns me is that she blatantly lies and can't be trusted, and I think the manager should be made aware of it.  I also want my name to be cleared of such an accusation.  I became aware of the situation because the person thought they were going to be fired, had packed up all their stuff in anticipation of it, and spent over a month with anxiety and hives thinking that we all hated her and wanted her out. She was told not to tell anyone. I don't want her to suffer any consequences from the office manager.

Comment: The person who is being fired was told not to tell anyone about why they were being fired?  That sounds very sketchy to me.  I'd definitely mention this to the store manager, although you shouldn't say "I heard from xxx that they're being fired"; it should be more like "I heard through the grapevine", or, better yet, "I saw xxx was packing up their things, could I ask about why?" and then think of some way to segue that into explaining that the office manager lied.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, any disinformation attempts should be dealt with on ASAP bases.
You should inform him about thew situation

Comment: That's... kind of what the question asks :)

Comment: i can remove the question part of my answer if it bother anyone, but about the first part i stand firm, any disinformation attempts should be dealt with ASAP

Comment: You can transfer that question into a comment if you require any clarification.  If that leaves only your first sentence, then you'll need to expand on that to describe why you feel that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

For the specific situation described in the question I don't think you should do anything. At most your store manager learned some inaccurate gossip (practically a redundant phrase!) which doesn't seem like it would have any meaningful impact on anything (it's not like you were accused of something relevant to the business, like embezzlement or skipping shifts).

Even if you really did want that other employee fired, what difference would that make? It may not even be the case that the office manager was being intentionally deceptive-- it might be his or her impression based on interactions between you and the other two employees in question.

For other situations involving your office manager it's harder to say. I don't have any idea what sorts of fabrications he or she has been producing, or how they've been delivered, or which goals those fabrications might be pursuing. But a good overall measure to take might be to develop some sort of relationship with the store manager.

You don't have to become best friends, but a modest degree of friendliness (or at least professional contact) with him will dilute the office manager's leverage as the only point of contact/source of information about the store and its employees. If your only interactions with the store manager are to point out specific times you think the office manager is lying about low-impact matters I think that things are likely to go poorly for you.

Comment: The office manager definitely knew she was being deceptive - no question in my mind. She has been causing similar problems with others.  I have a very good relationship with the manager already. What difference does it make?   I think a co-worker who blatantly lies has a huge impact on a workplace.

Comment: @Louise It's the difference between "all I know about the store is what the office manager tells me, and I believe her" and "I know Louise, that really doesn't sound like her. I'll ask what she thinks". A deceitful coworker can definitely have a big impact on the workplace, but doesn't necessarily, and can be valuable to the store/larger company either way. Angling to get her fired (and I don't see what other end goal you might have here) over events like you've described sounds chancy, especially if she's as important to the running of the store as you suggest.